# How do I initialize a pointer to an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to initialize a pointer to an array of pointers.  Here's an example:

```
class MyClass { };

// INTENT: define a pointer to an array of pointers to MyClass objects
MyClass* (*myPointer)[];

int main(void) {

  // INTENT: define and initialize an array of pointers to MyClass objects
  MyClass * tempArray [] = {
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
  };

  // INTENT: make myPointer point to the array just created
  myPointer = tempArray;

}
```

When I compile this I get:

```
./test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test2.cpp:15:19: error: cannot convert ‘MyClass* [2]’ to ‘MyClass* (*)[]’ in assignment
   myPointer = tempArray;
               ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The compiler is complaining because `myPointer` and `tempArray` are different types. You can see this clearly in the declarations. You need to declare them both as the same type in order for the assignment to work.

Comment: Or you need to change the assignment statement. Perhaps `myPointer = &tempArray` is what you want?

Comment: Try using `std::vector<MyClass *>`.  Vectors are a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: I want to avoid vectors because this is an embedded project.

Comment: FYI - embedded is not a good excuse to avoid STL and containers...

Comment: `MyClass* (*myPointer)[];` is not allowed in Standard C++, I recommend using standard mode for compilation to help catch this sort of mistake

Answer (score 2):

First, arrays are not pointers. You have to use the address-of:

```
 myPointer = &tempArray;
```

Next, when you write

```
T foo[] = { t1, t2 };
```

this is just short-hand notation for

```
T foo[2] = { t1, t2 };
```

Either use the correct type ([Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Cd6XX6MFhQ5yroC)):

```
MyClass* (*myPointer)[2];
```

or perhaps better use a `std::array<MyClass>` in the first place. And forget about raw owning pointers. Use smart pointers instead.

Comment: @NickReed fixed. I had to combine two wrong answers to get a correct one ;)

Comment: @NickReed That repl doesn't appear to be changed from the OP's code here.

Comment: Solid, have an upvote! Out of curiosity, would you happen to know why can't one convert between `foo[]` and `foo[2]`? I was trying to answer the question myself, but couldn't find the reasoning behind the compiler's hangup about that.

Comment: @NickReed i have to admit, I have no clue what a `foo[]` (or `MyClass* (*myPointer)[];`) actually is

Answer (score 1):

```
// INTENT: define a pointer to an array of pointers to MyClass objects
MyClass* (*myPointer)[];
```

You can't obmit the size of the array in declaration. You need this:

```
MyClass* (*myPointer)[2];
```

Then,

```
  MyClass * tempArray [] = {
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
  };

  // INTENT: make myPointer point to the array just created 
  myPointer = &tempArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

An array *decays* into a pointer to the first element. Since the element type is also a pointer, you can declare a variable that is a double-pointer and have it point at that element, eg:

```cpp
class MyClass { };

MyClass** myPointer;

int main(void) {

  MyClass * tempArray [] = {
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
  };

  myPointer = tempArray;
    // same as:
    // myPointer = &tempArray[0];

  ...
}
```

Comment: **BINGO** Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed!